# C Program Error

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ beginner, execution window disappears quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436108/c-beginner-execution-window-disappears-quickly)

I am beginner at C programming. But when I compile the programm, a problem occurs. The compiler create a .exe for the program, but when I open it, it appears and disappears in a second.

This error can be stopped by adding

```
SYSTEM("PAUSE");
```

at end of the program. But it will create a

> press any key to continue

at the end of program. What is the error of mine? Why the program appears and disappears in a hurry?

How do I stop it without adding the `system()` function? I'm using the GCC compiler.

Comment: Why shouldn't the program disappear in a hurry? :)

Comment: Learn from a better book and use a better IDE.

Comment: @PavanManjunath:i CANT SEE WHATS INSIDE IT  because it terminates in a hurry just in 1 millisecond

Comment: @GokulKtp You haven't told the program to wait for you. Thats why it terminates. As you've already mentioned yourself, use something like `system("pAUSE")` , `getchar` etc to tell your program to wait for you

Comment: Many, many duplicates, e.g. [C++ beginner, execution window disappears quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436108/c-beginner-execution-window-disappears-quickly) and [How can I get a Windows console to stay open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482444/how-can-i-get-a-windows-console-to-stay-open)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't an error. The program will terminate after finishing the code you programmed. If you want to input something try `scanf` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Run the program form a dos window instead of double clinking if you dont want to add a pause or scanf

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour of a program. When it reaches its end, it has done what it had to do, and so it has nothing more to do. And this brings the OS to stop and delete its process.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error. The program executes and disappears when it's execution has finished.

Comment: If you want to stop the program after it has done its main intended purpose, add the `system()` call which is (logically) better than using input functions like `getchar()` or `scanf()`.

Answer (score -1):

u can use an input function like `gets()` or `getchar()` or `scanf()` with no input variable  instead of `system()`

Comment: ******NEVER****** use `gets`. EVER. It is being removed from all standards (C, POSIX, etc.)

Comment: `gets` is no longer in the current C Standard (it was in [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), it isn't in [C11](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

Comment: oops! i knew that and still made the mistake! sorry!!